# Apache service can't access local drive

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, virtualhost

I know that Apache must use UNC paths for network resources when run as a service, but I have a local drive `I:`. It's not virtual drive, nor a mapped drive, it's a single physical disk inside the case. I keep getting this error in my logs

```
Syntax error on line X of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
<Directory "I:/path/to/web/root"> path is invalid.
```

However that path definitely exists. I can access it through a different UNC share, but then wouldn't every file access have go through SMB? Wouldn't this kill performance?

Answer (score 0):

Was just permissions. Somebody stopped the `SYSTEM` account from being able to access one directory in the chain between `I:` and the web root. o_O